# Accessing all photos in iphone photo library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

Is it possible to get all photos in an array or something from iPhone photo library ? UIImagePickerController allows to choose only one picture at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `ALAssetsLibrary`'s `-enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` to enumerate one or more assets groups and then enumerate the assets (photos) in each groups with `-[ALAssetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:]`. The documentation has all the details.

Answer (score 1):

USE ELCImagePickerController
used to display more than one asset images.